# C++ STL container priority queue initialisation

Tags: c++, stl

from
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/priority_queue/

```
//initialize (1)    
explicit priority_queue (const Compare& comp = Compare(),
                         const Container& ctnr = Container());


//range (2) 
template <class InputIterator>
         priority_queue (InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
                         const Compare& comp = Compare(),
                         const Container& ctnr = Container());
```

Based on answers to similar question on SO, I am using

```
priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<int> > pq
```

However, this definition doesn't match with either 1 or 2 given in the reference site. So how is this initialisation working?

Comment: It matches the first. Those are default arguments.

Comment: This reference should help clarify: [std::priority_queue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're only looking at the reference for the constructor.

The template parameter list you need to look at is the template parameter list *for the class template itself*:

```
template<
    class T,
    class Container = std::vector<T>,
    class Compare = std::less<typename Container::value_type>
> class priority_queue;
```

You're instantiating a `std::priority_queue` with all three template parameters given explicitly, and doing so using the first constructor (which is not a function template — the second constructor is) and taking the defaults of both its arguments.

- [`std::priority_queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue)
- [`std::priority_queue::priority_queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue)